Symmetric measurable function
I came across the following interesting problem and I am not sure how to approach it:
Let $f:[0,\,1]^2\to[0,\,1]$ be measurable and symmetric, i.e. $f(x,y) = f(y,x)$. Define $F(x)=\int_0^1f(x,\,y)\text{d}y$ and assume for almost all $x$
$$(F(x))^2+2\int_0^1f(x,\,y)F(y)\text{d}y=3\int_0^1(F(y))^2\text{d}y\qquad (*)$$
Does $f$ have to be constant?
I suspect the answer is no if the requirement that $f$ has to be non-negative is dropped: we can consider $f(x,y) = g(x)g(y)$, which reduces the above equation to
$$g^2(x)\left(\int g\right)^2 +  g(x)\int g\int g^2=3\int g^2\left(\int g\right)^2.$$
This has two solutions but one is always negative. However, I have no idea where to even start with the actual problem.

You say  "the requirement...be non-negative is dropped.."  Be careful, the function $f$ must be bounded to be integrable.

Let $c=F(y)=\int_{0}^{1}f(y,y)dy$. Observe that $c\geq 0$. Also note that $F(x)\geq 0$  by the positivity assumption on $f$. We have the equation
$$(F(x))^2+2c F(x)-3 c^2=(F(x)-c)(F(x)+3c)=0$$
Then $F(x)=c$. Therefore $F^{\prime}(x)=0$. That is $F(x)$ is constant in $x$. I am stuck here though!

Try $$f(x,y) = a_0 + a_1 (x + y - 2 x y)$$
For suitable constants $a_0$ and $a_1$ (in fact for $0 \le a_0 \le 1$ with $-a_0 \le a_1 \le 1-a_0$), $0 \le f(x,y) \le 1$, and your equation (*) is true for all $x$.

Thanks, that's a nice construct. Was there specific motivation behind it?

Polynomials of low degree are a good place to look for examples.
